# Garbage elements in the array when inserting at beginning of the array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am starting out with data structures now, I wrote a simple code to insert an element at the beginning of the array but it's giving me garbage elements in the array. My approach is copy all the elements to a new array of size + 1 and then shift all the elements to insert at beginning just like a vector works.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void insertAtFront(int arr[], int n, int element)
{
    int* temp = new int[n + 1];

    for(auto i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        temp[i] = arr[i];
    }

    temp[n] = 0;

    delete[] arr;
    arr = temp;

    // Shifting elements
    for(int i = n - 2; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
    }

    arr[0] = element;
}


int main()
{
    int* arr = new int[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = i + 1;
    }
    cout << "Enter element to insert: ";
    int element;
    cin >> element;
    insertAtFront(arr, 10, element);

    for(int i = 0; i < 11; ++i)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The fact you have variables named `arr` in both `main()` and `insertAtFront()` does not mean they name the same thing.  `arr` in `insertAtFront()` is a pointer that is passed by value, so a COPY of the value of `arr` in `main()` is passed.  So the assignment `arr = temp` in that function is NOT VISIBLE to `main()`.  As far as `main()` is concerned, its `arr` is unchanged but what it points to is released, so the loop printing elements has undefined behaviour.    If you want changes to `arr` in `insertAtFront()` to be visible to `main()`, then the argument needs to be passed by reference.

Comment: But, aren't the arrays are passed by pointers automatically in C?, Whatever change we do in the function, shouldn't it automatically reflect in the arr in main?

Comment: Yes, when an array is passed to a function, a pointer (to its first element) is passed.   However, the POINTER is passed by value, which is why the assignment `arr = temp` (`arr` and `temp` are pointers) is not visible to `main()`.    Your code is assigning the pointer.     (And, BTW, although you get away with it in this case because C++ and C do the same thing,  it is often not a good idea to assume C and C++ work the same way).

Comment: How do I pass it by reference then?

Comment: Change the first argument of `insertAtFront()` from `int arr[]` (which is equivalent to `int *arr`) to `int *&arr`.    Or pass a pointer to a pointer (`int **arr`), in which case ALL accesses or assignments of `arr` in the function will need to be changed to `(*arr)`.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @Peter, the problem is that the pointer `arr` was being passes to the `insertAtFront()` function by value and hence the changes in the `arr` were not visible in the main function. Here is the updated code which fixes this issue.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void insertAtFront(int **arr, int n, int element)
{
    int* temp = new int[n + 1];

    for(auto i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        temp[i] = (*arr)[i];
    }

    delete[] (*arr);
    *arr = temp;

    // Shifting elements
    for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        (*arr)[i + 1] = (*arr)[i];
    }

    *arr[0] = element;
}


int main()
{
    int* arr = new int[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        arr[i] = i + 1;
    }
    cout << "Enter element to insert: ";
    int element;
    cin >> element;
    insertAtFront(&arr, 10, element);

    for(int i = 0; i < 11; ++i)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";

    delete[] arr;
    return 0;
}
```